# Thread.join() gives me an error?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm working on an assignment where the main function creates a main thread which runs a function called `run()`. Inside the run function, I'm trying to make it so that a new thread is created with a customer object (simulating that a customer walks to the shop and leaves). Once one customer object is declared, it runs a function which simulates the person coming into the shop and then leaving.

I have the main function here. Inside, it declares a main thread which executes the `run()` function, inside the run function I'm trying to create a new thread, and each time a new thread is created, a new customer object is created as well and the customerID is incremented. Then I'm trying to implement `newCustThread.join()` so that the previous customer thread finishes before the while loop is continued and the next customer thread is created.

**Main:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "classBarberShop.h"
#include "classCustomer.h"
using namespace std;

void run();
void createCustomerObj(int customerID, BarberShop newShop);



int WAIT_TIME = 3;
BarberShop newShop();
int customerID = 1;

int main(){
    thread newThread(run);

    return 0;
}

void run(){
    while (customerID <= 5){
        thread newCustThread(Customer newCustomer(int customerID, BarberShop newShop));
        newCustThread.join(); //    <===== ERROR HERE

        customerID++;
    }
    return;
}
```

**classBarberShop.h**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum bState {
    FULL = -1,
    EMPTY = 0,
    OCCUPIED = 1,
    SLEEPING = 2,
    DONE = 3,
    WAITING = 4
};

class BarberShop {

public:
    BarberShop(){
        chairNum = 5;
        barber = SLEEPING;

        for (int i = 0; i < chairNum; i++){
            chairState[i] = EMPTY;
        }
    }

    bool findChair(int passingCustomer){
        int getEmptyChair = getFirstEmptyChair();

        if (getEmptyChair == FULL){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            chairState[getEmptyChair] = OCCUPIED;
        }

        return true;
    }

    int getHairCut(int customer){
        if (barber == SLEEPING){

            barber = OCCUPIED;
            return SLEEPING;
        }
        else if (barber == OCCUPIED){
            bool chairFound = findChair(customer);

            if (chairFound == false){
                return FULL;
            }
            else{
                /*while (barber == OCCUPIED){

                }*/

                for (int i = 0; i < chairNum; i++){
                    if (chairState[i] == OCCUPIED){
                        chairState[i] = EMPTY;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                barber = OCCUPIED;
                return WAITING;
            }
        }
        else{
            barber = OCCUPIED;
            return DONE;
        }
    }

    int leaveBarberShop(int customer){
        bool isWaiting = isAnyoneWaiting();

        if (isWaiting == true){
            barber = DONE;
        }
        else{
            barber = SLEEPING;
        }

        //notify();
    }

    int getFirstEmptyChair(){
        for (int i = 0; i < chairNum; i++){
            if (chairState[i] == EMPTY){
                return i;
            }

            return FULL;
        }
    }

    bool isAnyoneWaiting(){
        for (int i = 0; i < chairNum; i++){
            if (chairState[i] == OCCUPIED){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

//private:
    int chairNum;
    int barber;
    int chairState[5];
};
```

**classCustomer.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classBarberShop.h"
using namespace std;

class Customer {

    int customer;
    BarberShop shop;
    int bstate;
    int HAIRCUT_TIME = 5;

    Customer(int passingCustomer, BarberShop passingShop) {
        shop = passingShop;
        customer = passingCustomer;
        run();
    }

    void run() {
        int sleepingTime = (int)(HAIRCUT_TIME * rand());

        cout << "ENTERING SHOP: Customer [" << customer << "] entering barber shop for haircut." << endl;

        bstate = OCCUPIED;
        bstate = shop.getHairCut(customer);

        if (bstate == WAITING){
            cout << "Barber's busy: Customer [" << customer << "] has waited and now wants a haircut." << endl;
        }
        else if (bstate == SLEEPING){
            cout << "Barber's asleep: Customer [" << customer << "] is waking him up and getting a haircut." << endl;
        }
        else if (bstate == FULL){
            cout << "Barber shop is full: Customer [" << customer << "] is leaving shop." << endl;
            return;
        }
        else {
            cout << "HAIRCUT: Customer [" << customer << "] is getting haircut." << endl;
        }

        //******Suspend thread here?
        cout << "LEAVING SHOP: Customer [" << customer << "] haircut finished: leaving shop." << endl;
        bstate = shop.leaveBarberShop(customer);

        return;
    }
};
```

The program is run when you create a customer object. When you create the object, because of the constructor, the function `run()` in the `classCustomer.h` is run.

I don't understand why it is not working. I'll be grateful for the help. Threading is very new to me :/

Comment: You don't seem to be giving your thread any code to run.

Comment: I just want to point out that the best description of your error that you've given us is "an error" and that we can't even run the code to find out for ourselves.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I added more detail to the problem. It seems as though I have a few more errors than expected :( sorry not giving the code right away. I was in the process of editing it after I posted it! Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Note a terminology problem ... the function 'main' _is_ your first thread.  The thread named "newThread",  might start in function named 'run', but if 'main' completes, any thread started by main also terminates ---  at least on Linux.  I suggest you invoke sleep in main after you start newThread to see if you can get more to happen.

Comment: Just to add a bit more to what @DOUGLASO.MOEN said:  when `main()` returns the process is exited which will terminate any running threads.  So you can either prevent `main()` from returning until your threads have completed their work (for example, by using `join()`), or you can have `main()` call `pthread_exit()` (or similar), which will cause the thread that is running `main()` to terminate without exiting the entire process.  At that point, the process will end when all threads have exited or when one of the threads calls `exit()` (or similar).

Comment: What Michael said - better solution ... invoke join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before exiting main() join the inner thread:

```
int main()
{
   thread newThread(run);
   newThread.join();  // <-- missing line
   return 0;
}
```